# Updating Ubuntu updates python versions?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04, python-install

I am currently running ubuntu 16.04, I have a multiple versions of python3 installed in my system. They are kind of messed up with failure while building these versions. I was earlier planning on upgrading to ubuntu 18, but now does these python issues that I have in 16 will also be carried forward in 18 after the update?

Comment: There is a chance tha the automatic system upgrade will fail. It is usually recommended to remove all 3rd party software/packages before upgrading. This question is better to be asked on Unix&Linux stackexchange. Describe there in more detail how you installed those versions of Python and what exactly you mean by "messed up" (error messages, etc.)